# hide all other child elements and add close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm still learning javascript, so please bear with me!

I'm attempting to create a menu using Jquery, so far I've managed to make the child ul of any given li show, but I'm unsure how to make only one appear at a time.

I would also like include a close button within each child ul which hides the ul it's situated within. I've somehow un knowingly achieved this, but I'm not sure how, any explanation would be great. 
Or if there is a proper way to do it that would also be appreciated.

```js
$("ul ul").hide();
     $("li").click(function (event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         $(this).children('ul').toggle();
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
      <li>Item 1
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
            <div class="close">
            close
            </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 2
        <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul> 
      </li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Move the `$("ul ul").hide();` inside the click handler to show only one at a time (ie hide all, show clicked).  There are other ways, but this is the simplest with what you have.

Comment: You question is not very clear... building multi-level menus could become very tricky. I recommend using a library such as bootstrap, [see this example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h) or [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/menu/)... or use a template, like [this one](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3)

Answer (score 0):

Your close item works because of your `$(this).children('ul').toggle()` and the fact that you're making use of `<div>` element for your close. When you click on the inner `<li>` elements, the `$(this)` refers to **that** `<li>` element, which has no children. When you click on the `<div>`, you're also successfully clicking on `Item 1` (triggering the **parent** `$("li").click`), which in turn triggers the `$(this).children('ul').toggle()` on the children successfully. Unfortunately, a `<div>` here would be invalid markup, and you're better off simply using an `<li>` element and setting up a custom click handle for `$('.close')`.

As stated above, you're triggering a 'double-click'. To get around this, the best approach would be to set up an individual click handle for just the parent `<li>`, which toggles children. Then you can toggle display of other elements with a handler on `li li` which hides `$(this).parent().parent().siblings().children()` (with two parent layers to cover the `<ul>` as well).

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$("li").click(function(event) {
  $(this).children('ul').show();
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$("li li").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().siblings().children().hide();
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
  $(this).parent().parent().siblings().children().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Item 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li class="close">
        close
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```